# C++ calling functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers, compiler-errors

I'm new to C++ and I have this problem that the compiler is throwing at me whenever I compile my program. From what I've learnt so far you have a class in which you declare constructors and functions. Then after the class you implement the functions. Then in the main you call/manipulate them. I was writing a linkedlist program but I kept getting this annoying compiler error:

> error: request for member `'get_number'` in `'test'`, which is of non-class type `'LinkList*'`

My original program was quite longer than the below, but as I kept getting the above error I wrote a really simple program just to see where the error was being thrown. Despite writing it very simple I got the EXACT same error. So I'm doing something wrong when I'm calling the function that I have declared and implemented.

If someone could just help me point out what I'm doing wrong and why I can't call that function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class LinkList 
{
public:
    int result;

    //declaring the constructor
    LinkList(int i);

    //declaring simple function
    int get_number();
};

//Implementing the constructor
LinkList::LinkList(int i) 
{
    result = i; 
};

//implementing test function
int LinkList::get_number()
{
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    LinkList *test = new LinkList(5);

    int getting_number = 0;

    //Error trigger:
    test.get_number();

    cout<<getting_number;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `test` is a pointer to `LinkList`. The `.` operator is used on instance/reference types. For pointers, you use the `->` operator like `test->get_number()`, or the dereference-dot like `(*test).get_number()`. Also, bonus - you're not assigning the `get_number()` result to anything. You probably wanted this: `int getting_number() = test->get_number()`.

Comment: +1 for writing " a really simple program just to see where the error was being thrown". You could have made it even simpler, but still, +1. http://sscce.org

Comment: @birryree - Typo? You meant `int getting_number = test->get_number()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test is a pointer to a LinkList object, you have to access properties and members on test using the arrow operator (->), for example: test->get_number();

Or you could just not create a pointer to the object and create a normal object.

Comment: Thanks. I'm coming from a java background. Problem fixed!

Comment: What is a "normal object"? @user992055 if you only want the code to compile, this answer is ok. However, your coding suggests you need a deeper insight into what is happening under the hood in C++. I suggest you also check out more complete answers.

Comment: Normal object wasn't really what I ment, I ment a non-pointer object.

Answer (score 3):

Objects in C++ are either in **automatic storage** or **dynamic storage** (there's also **static storage**, but that's beyond the scope of the question).

When you create an object with `new`, you create it in dynamic storage and return a pointer to it.

Members of an object referenced by a pointer are accessed with the `->` operator:

```
test->get_number();
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(*test).get_number();
```

#### Bonus point 1:

You also have a memory leak in your program, as the memory allocated for `test` is never freed. You need to explicitly call `delete test` to free it. (in this case it's not an *actual* memory leak since the system reclaims the memory on the program exit, but you should know this for the future).

In this case you should however use automatic storage objects:

```
LinkedList test(5);
//...
test.get_number();
```

This way, you don't need to worry about memory management and it's also preferable to use automatically managed objects instead of dynamic ones.

#### Bonus point 2:

In c++, non-pod types are initialized before entering the constructor body, so you should start using initializer lists:

```
LinkList::LinkList(int i) :
result(i) 
{
};
```

This prevents double initialization and is an easy optimization trick. Even if for this particular case the difference is not noticeable, you should start getting into the habit of initializing members like this early on.

Comment: Your bonus points are an excellent way of getting the extra information that may not be crucial now, but will be later, presented in a very readable way such as to answer the question and add on after.

Answer (score 3):

just use

```
LinkedList test(5);
```

instead of

```
LinkList *test = new LinkList(5);
```

if you insist on using the new variant you need to change the

```
test.get_number();
```

to

```
test->get_number();
```

and free (delete) your test object before exiting the function;

and even then you are not assigning the return value from get_number to anything, so your getting_number varaible is still 0;

Answer (score 0):

`test` is not a `LinkList` itself but a pointer to one. Therefore,

```
test.get_number();
```

should be:

```
test->get_number();
```

This is just a shortcut for:

```
(*test).get_number();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct. `test` is a `LinkedList*`, a pointer to a `LinkedList`. You must call it with `test->get_number()`. The dot-call is only for non-pointer types.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will say "stop right there". This is not Java and it is not C#. It is C++. In Java and C# you always create your objects with new.

In C++ you don't always create them that way.

Your better code would be simply:

```
int main() 
{     
    LinkList test(5);
    int getting_number = test.get_number();      
    std::cout<<getting_number << '\n';      
    return 0; 
}
```